# Read excel column and re-write into excel as data format using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

My excel spreadsheet is for the form as below.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Part 1- 20210910 | 55 |
| Part 2- 20210829 | 45 |
| Part 3- 20210912 | 2 |

I would like to take the strings from Column A "Part A- 20210910" but read it using Pandas as "2021/09/10", a date format. How could I implement this?

Comment: It's not clear what 'dat**A** format' means? Is it 'dat**E** format'?

Comment: My apologies, I have amended this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.extract(r'(\d{8})').astype('datetime64')
print(df)

# Output:
           A   B
0 2021-09-10  55
1 2021-08-29  45
2 2021-09-12   2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it was not what I was looking for.  Apologies if my question was not informative enough.

Comment: Many thanks. I cant  figure what ' .extract(r'(\d{8})') ' does.

Answer (score 1):

My beginner way of doing it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx')
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')).apply(lambda x: x[1]).apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%Y%m%d'))
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. I had knowledge of the ' pd.to_datetime ' but could not figure out how to apply it the way I was looking for.